# google play geofence onHandleIntent

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am developing android app with geofence which released in this year.

My understanding is when the users get into (or out of) the fence it should trigger onHandleIntent method However, I have difficulty to trigger to onHandleIntent method

I have checked for 3 days to figure it out  but I evetually could not.

so I need anyone's help.

there is my code  I really hope anyone could help me out.

```
    ///// MainActivity

    package com.example.geofence;


    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import android.app.PendingIntent;
    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.IntentFilter;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
    import android.text.TextUtils;
    import android.util.Log;

    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
    import com.google.android.gms.location.Geofence;
    import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient;
    import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient.OnAddGeofencesResultListener;

    import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
    import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationStatusCodes;

    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements 
                                        ConnectionCallbacks, 
                                        OnConnectionFailedListener, 
                                        OnAddGeofencesResultListener
                                         {
    private IntentFilter mIntentFilter;
    private LocationClient locationClient;
    private LocationRequest locatRequest;

    private PendingIntent intent;
    private List<Geofence> mGeoList;
    private Context mContext;
    private Geofence companyLocation;
    private  GeofenceSampleReceiver mBroadcastReceiver;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mContext = this;

        locatRequest = null;
        mGeoList = new ArrayList<Geofence>();

        intent = null;
        locationClient = new LocationClient(this,this,this);

        mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        mIntentFilter.addAction("com.example.geofence.ACTION_GEOFENCES_ADDED");
        mIntentFilter.addCategory("com.example.geofence.CATEGORY_LOCATION_SERVICES");
        mBroadcastReceiver = new GeofenceSampleReceiver();
    }




    @Override
     protected void onStart() {

        companyLocation =  new Geofence.Builder()
        .setRequestId("1")
        .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
        .setCircularRegion(
                49.220531, -122.986772, (float)50)
        .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)
        .build();

        mGeoList.add(companyLocation);
        locationClient.connect();
        super.onStart();    

     }



    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        intent = getTransitionPendingIntent();

        locatRequest = LocationRequest.create();
           locatRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
           locatRequest.setInterval(5000);

           try{
               addGeofence();
           }catch(UnsupportedOperationException e){
            Toast.makeText(this, "add_geofences_already_requested_error",
                 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
       //    locationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locatRequest, intent);


    }

    public void addGeofence(){
        locationClient.addGeofences(mGeoList,intent , this);  

    }

     private PendingIntent getTransitionPendingIntent() {
            // Create an explicit Intent
            Intent localIntent = new Intent(this,
                    ReceiveTransitionsIntentService.class);
            /*
             * Return the PendingIntent
             */
            return PendingIntent.getService(
                    this,
                    0,
                    localIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }






     @Override
     protected void onStop() {

            locationClient.disconnect();
            super.onStop();

     }

    @Override
    public void onAddGeofencesResult(int statusCode, String[] geofenceRequestIds) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();

        if(LocationStatusCodes.SUCCESS == statusCode){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

     broadcastIntent.setAction("com.example.android.geofence.ACTION_GEOFENCES_ADDED")
                            .addCategory("com.example.android.geofence.CATEGORY_LOCATION_SERVICES")
                                    .putExtra("com.example.android.geofence.EXTRA_GEOFENCE_STATUS","test");
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "AddGeoError", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mContext).sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);

    }



    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult arg0) {        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         int code = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
         switch(code){

                case  ConnectionResult.SERVICE_MISSING :{
                    Toast.makeText(this, "SERVICE_MISSING " + code + " ConnectionResult.SERVICE_MISSING " +ConnectionResult.SERVICE_MISSING, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;

                }
                case ConnectionResult.SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED:{

                    Toast.makeText(this, "SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED " + code + " ConnectionResult.SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED " + ConnectionResult.SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    break;
                }
                default:{
                    Toast.makeText(this, "start " + code, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
    }



     @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
    }



    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
    }



    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, mIntentFilter);
        //locationClient.connect();
        super.onResume();
    }


    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        locationClient = null;
    }

    /*
     * Handle results returned to this Activity by other Activities started with
     * startActivityForResult(). In particular, the method onConnectionFailed() in
     * GeofenceRemover and GeofenceRequester may call startResolutionForResult() to
     * start an Activity that handles Google Play services problems. The result of this
     * call returns here, to onActivityResult.
     * calls
     */

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(
                int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    }




     /**
     * Define a Broadcast receiver that receives updates from connection listeners and
     * the geofence transition service.
     */
    public class GeofenceSampleReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        /*
         * Define the required method for broadcast receivers
         * This method is invoked when a broadcast Intent triggers the receiver
         */
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            // Check the action code and determine what to do
            String action = intent.getAction();

            // Intent contains information about errors in adding or removing geofences
         if (TextUtils.equals(action, "com.example.geofence.ACTION_GEOFENCES_ADDED")) {

                handleGeofenceStatus(context, intent);

            // Intent contains information about a geofence transition
            } else if (TextUtils.equals(action, "com.example.geofence.ACTION_GEOFENCE_TRANSITION")) {

                handleGeofenceTransition(context, intent);

            // The Intent contained an invalid action
            } else {

                Toast.makeText(context,"error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        /**
         * If you want to display a UI message about adding or removing geofences, put it here.
         *
         * @param context A Context for this component
         * @param intent The received broadcast Intent
         */
        private void handleGeofenceStatus(Context context, Intent intent) {

        }

        /**
         * Report geofence transitions to the UI
         *
         * @param context A Context for this component
         * @param intent The Intent containing the transition
         */
        private void handleGeofenceTransition(Context context, Intent intent) {
            /*
             * If you want to change the UI when a transition occurs, put the code
             * here. The current design of the app uses a notification to inform the
             * user that a transition has occurred.
             */
        }

        /**
         * Report addition or removal errors to the UI, using a Toast
         *
         * @param intent A broadcast Intent sent by ReceiveTransitionsIntentService
         */
        private void handleGeofenceError(Context context, Intent intent) {

        }
    }


}



///// ReceiveTransitionsIntentService

    package com.example.geofence;

    import java.util.List;

    import android.app.IntentService;
    import android.app.NotificationManager;
    import android.app.PendingIntent;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
    import android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.google.android.gms.location.Geofence;
    import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient;

    public class ReceiveTransitionsIntentService extends IntentService {

    /**
     * Sets an identifier for the service
     */
    private Context mContext;
    public ReceiveTransitionsIntentService(Context c) {

        super("ReceiveTransitionsIntentService");
        mContext =c;
    }

    /**
     * Handles incoming intents
     *@param intent The Intent sent by Location Services. This
     * Intent is provided
     * to Location Services (inside a PendingIntent) when you call
     * addGeofences()
     */
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // First check for errors

        //Toast.makeText(mContext, "onHandleIntent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if (LocationClient.hasError(intent)) {
            // Get the error code with a static method
            int errorCode = LocationClient.getErrorCode(intent);
            // Log the error
            Log.e("ReceiveTransitionsIntentService",
                    "Location Services error: " +
                    Integer.toString(errorCode));
            /*
             * You can also send the error code to an Activity or
             * Fragment with a broadcast Intent
             */
        /*
         * If there's no error, get the transition type and the IDs
         * of the geofence or geofences that triggered the transition
         */
        } else {


              int transitionType = LocationClient.getGeofenceTransition(intent);
            if(transitionType == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER || 
                    transitionType == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT){
                List<Geofence> geofences = LocationClient.getTriggeringGeofences(intent);
                String[] geofenceIds = new String [geofences.size()];
                for(int i = 0; i <geofences.size(); i++){
                     geofenceIds[i] = geofences.get(i).getRequestId();
                }
                String ids = "1";
                String transition = ((transitionType == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER ) ?"you are in":"you are out");
                Toast.makeText(mContext, transition, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                sendNotification(transition,ids);
                //FOR THE NOTIFICATION.

                //NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                  //      (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            }




        } 
    }




    private void sendNotification(String transitionType, String ids) {

        // Create an explicit content Intent that starts the main Activity
        Intent notificationIntent =
                new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);

        // Construct a task stack
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);

        // Adds the main Activity to the task stack as the parent
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);

        // Push the content Intent onto the stack
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);

        // Get a PendingIntent containing the entire back stack
        PendingIntent notificationPendingIntent =
                stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        // Get a notification builder that's compatible with platform versions >= 4
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

        // Set the notification contents
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
               .setContentTitle(
                       transitionType+ " geofence_transition_notification_title " +ids)
               .setContentIntent(notificationPendingIntent);

        // Get an instance of the Notification manager
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        // Issue the notification
        mNotificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
    }



}
```

Comment: and  on my Manifest  I have  -service android:exported="false" android:name="com.example.geofence.ReceiveTransitionsIntentService"
and uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"

Comment: Why did you post your entire Activity code?  It is too much to read.  Just point us to the relevant problem snippet.

Comment: @user1979727 is this app works perfectly ?

Answer (score 0):

Your radius is set to 50 which means you need to travel 50 meters from your location in order to trigger the handle. Have you tried using a 2m radius?

Comment: Yes i've had so many trials  with different raduis  like  2, 5, 10 ,1000 meters. But it never run correctly.

Comment: I did have the same problem and after two days it started working... Transitions seem to take quite a long time to register.

A few things; check that the IntentService is running by looking on the phone's Settings->Apps->Running. Should be an extra google service in there somewhere. 
Try setting up the IntentService from onAddedGeofence and outputting something in the broadcast receiver to check everything is hooking up correctly.
If everything is fine, your app might not be setup to handle onPause/stop well, so keep your phone on with the app open for 5 minutes after you've left a fence.

Answer (score 0):

In your onCreate() method, you should instantiate the **GoogleApiClient**:

```
    mApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();

    mApiClient.connect();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you need a LocationRequest to Monitoring geofence location...

If you use google maps at same time. Your geofence monitoring will works! because google maps make LocationRequest and geofence see it...

Then if you need be autonomous in geofence monitoring you need make a LocationRequest handler...

[Google Api LocationRequest](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderClient)

Example Code

```
    FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient = new   FusedLocationProviderClient(activity);
    fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(getLocationRequest(), getPendingIntent());


private LocationRequest getLocationRequest() {
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();

    mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    return mLocationRequest;
}

private PendingIntent getPendingIntent() {
    // Reuse the PendingIntent if we already have it.
    Log.e(TAG, "Creating Monitoring Geofence...");
    if (mGeofencePendingIntent != null) {
        return mGeofencePendingIntent;
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(activity, LocationService.class);
    // We use FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT so that we get the same pending intent back when
    // calling addGeofencesTask() and removeGeofences().
    mGeofencePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(activity, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    return mGeofencePendingIntent;
}
```

In this code you take a Location Request at 10 seconds... And geofence monitoring each 10 seconds geo zone...

Answer (score -1):

```
return PendingIntent.getService(
                    this,
                    0,
                    localIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

should change to:

```
return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                    this,
                    0,
                    localIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```